# Building Yocto on Pandaboard

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, yocto, bitbake, pandaboard

I am  building  yocto-poky with meta-ivi on Pandaboard. I have seen [this](https://maniacbug.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/pandayocto/) thread saying that only denzil or earlier  versions of poky is supporting pandaboard.
I tried "denzil" but got this error

```
Bitbake version 1.19.1 is required and version 1.15.1 was found Failed to fetch test data from the network and the message Please ensure your network is configured correctly is printed.
```

then I tried with "dora" and  got this error

```
error: implicit declaration of function 'wl_proxy_marshal_constructor' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

Any suggestion for implementation of of poky,meta-ivi,meta-ti versions for running in image on the Pandaboard?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I guess the second is from the compiler.. is it ? if yes then there should be a log.do_compile which should be showing a complete log of what happened ...

Comment: @theadnangondal  yes... and [this](https://communities.intel.com/message/232394) explaining the cause of error . my version is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Support for 14.04 ubuntu has stopped. Please upgrade and then reframe the question.

Comment: @abunickabhi Are you a time traveler ?

Comment: No I am not, I just like 2015 questions a lot.